# How can I change string splitting style in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to change string splitting style. How can I do that?
eq. Now:

```
String myVar = "Some " +
                  "text";
```

What I want:

```
String myVar = "Some " 
                  + "text";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to *Preferences*

   - <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> on the Mac
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> on Windows/Linux
2. Select *Editor -> Code Style -> Java*
3. Select the *Wrapping and Braces* tab
4. Tick **"Operation sign on the next line"** under **"Binary expressions"**

[image: IntelliJ settings]